# django-rest-framework : restrict RelatedField queryset according to request

Tags: python, django, authorization, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a ForeignKey

*models.py*

```
class B(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(contrib.auth.User)

class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

*serializers.py*

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ['b']
```

*views.py*

```
class AViewSet(iewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = A.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ASerializer
```

Now what I want is to restrict the `A.b` values to the `B` instances owned by the currently logged-in user.

I know how to enforce that at saving-time, but I would like to only present the relevant queryset in the dropdown choice in the [browsable API interface](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/).

If one can [define a *queryset* argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument) on the *RelatedField*, it's static and can't depend on the current request.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could try overriding queryset in **init** of serializer.
something like

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MySerializerClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.context.get('request', None):
        field = self.fields.get('b')
        field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(user=request.user)
```

Current user shall be accessible through self.context.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the get_queryset:

```
class AViewSet(iewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ASerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return A.objects.filter(b__user = user)
```

ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: no, what I want is to filter the list of B available to set on `A.b` attr, not filtering the list of A.